# Как вывести номер каждой строки из запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно вывести номер каждой строки, начиная с 1, 2, 3 и т.д.?

```
require_once 'conf.php';
  $h = 60;
  $query ="SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
  if($result)
  {
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      echo "<p class="."marr marr-gg netral".">Test</p>";
      for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
      {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
              for ($j = 0 ; $j < 1 ; ++$j) echo "<p>"."<img src="."/engine/modules/load/uploads/avatar/face.php?username=$row[1]&amp;size=40"." alt="."$row[1]"." class="."".">"."$row[1] - ".floor(($row[2]/$h))."</p>";
      }

      mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

  mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: переменная $i это и есть номер строки, ее и выводите

Comment: @Mike тогда нумерация начинается с 0, как сделать, чтобы она начиналась с 1?

Comment: @Mike прошу прощения, прибавил к i 1, и все стало как нужно, спасибо за ответ.